# Convert string datetime with 9 digits in last to ISO format datetime object in python

Tags: python, django, format, python-datetime, iso8601

I have string datetime (eg: "2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289776Z"). I want to convert the same in ISO format.

I tried below

```py
>>> datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289776Z")
```

But it is throwing error.

> `ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289776Z`

It is working if I give only 6 digits in the last without Z.

Below example is working for me, however not working for the strings with 9 digits and z in the end:

```py
>>> datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289")

datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 11, 6, 19, 32, 776289)
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289")` For me on Python 3.10.5 this gives the expected `datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 11, 6, 19, 32, 776289)`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `timestamp[:-4]` on the time string?

Comment: This is working for me too. But I want to convert below string. 

"2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289776Z"

Comment: @SaurabhVerma in your question you said `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289") o/p-> datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 11, 6, 19, 32, 778394)` There's a discrepancy between 776289 and 778394

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal no, OP said that `.776289` in the input string resulted in `778394` microseconds in the resulting datetime.

Comment: @slothrop Missed that difference, my mistake. Seems that OP just made a copying mistake, since it's correct now.

Comment: (i) restrict the number of digits after decimal to 6 (ii) change `Z` to `+00:00`. BTW both seem to be a restriction added by the library, not the ISO standard (which allows arbitrary number of digits after decimal and `Z` for zulu time).

Comment: @SaurabhVerma: that will not work for the very simply reason that the "resolution" of `datetime` is a microsecond, so you can not store something like `0.0000001`, the smallest fraction is `0.000001`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If Python 3.11 is available

If you can upgrade to Python 3.11, then `fromisoformat` can handle this:

```
# Python 3.11 and above only
dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289776Z")
print(dt)
```

giving

```
2022-11-11 06:19:32.776289+00:00
```

### Earlier versions of Python

If you're restricted to earlier versions of Python, then as @SalmanA said in the comments, you can get to a valid timestamp by (1) trimming the microseconds down to 6 digits, using `re.sub`, and (2) replacing `Z` with `+00:00` (`str.replace` will do that).

This assumes the timestamp is otherwise validly formatted (e.g. no letter `Z` anywhere else in the string).

For example:

```
import datetime
import re

def clean_str(ts):
    return re.sub("(\d{6})(\d+)", r"\1", ts).replace("Z", "+00:00")

tests = ["2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289776Z",
         "2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289Z",
         "2022-11-11T06:19:32.7762897+03:00",
         "2022-11-11T06:19:32.776Z"]

for i, ts in enumerate(tests, 1):
    clean = clean_str(ts)
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(clean)
    print(f"({i}): {ts} -> {clean} -> {dt}")
```

giving:

```
(1): 2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289776Z -> 2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289+00:00 -> 2022-11-11 06:19:32.776289+00:00
(2): 2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289Z -> 2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289+00:00 -> 2022-11-11 06:19:32.776289+00:00
(3): 2022-11-11T06:19:32.7762897+03:00 -> 2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289+03:00 -> 2022-11-11 06:19:32.776289+03:00
(4): 2022-11-11T06:19:32.776Z -> 2022-11-11T06:19:32.776+00:00 -> 2022-11-11 06:19:32.776000+00:00
```

Note that as (1) and (3) show, the microseconds are truncated, not rounded, i.e. `32.776289776` goes to `32.776289` not `32.776290`. (And the same goes for the native Python 3.11 solution.) If you wanted true rounding then you would need to parse the string further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more "permissive" parser with `dateutil`. Indeed, you install that package [**`python-dateutil`** <sup>[PyPi]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/). This will parse with an arbitrary number of digits, *but*… `datetime` has a *resolution* of a microsecond, this means that it will not store the details *after* six digits, so it will just ignore the rest of the digits:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.isoparse('2022-11-11T06:19:32.776289776Z')
datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 11, 6, 19, 32, 776289, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

The `…776` part is thus omitted.